# How do I use the NETWORKDAYS formula to calculate the days an item has been open while returning a count of days open on items with no completion date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Table tracking days open using requested on and completion date

[image]

See image for visual.

I'm using `=NETWORKDAYS(D3,G3,L4:L16)` where D3 is "Requested on", G3 is "Completion Date", & L4:L16 is applicable holidays. This works for line items that have a completion date but I would like a count of days open from todays date (Dynamic) for line items without a completion date as well instead of the negative number.

I tried using a filter & a today function but get invalid returns.

```
=NETWORKDAYS(D3,G3,L4:L16,FILTER(G3:G14,G3,=today)
```

I'm probably using the filter and =today functions wrong, trying to have it track days open from the requested on date until today which is dynamic, +1 for every day.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, just replace `G3` with `if(g3="",today(),g3)`. If that is not what you want, add desired results to your visual.

Comment: This is perfect actually, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Ron!